# Is there any way to know when was an object created?

Tags: c#

I have no practical need for this, but I was wondering:

is there anyway in C# to know, for any two arbitrary objects, which one was created first?

Comment: Would you be asking one object if it was created before another object? Or a method that was passed both objects?

Answer (score 8):

No. Unless the object has a read-only property that stored the date and time that the object was created, there's no way to know.

Answer (score 8):

Only if, inside the constructor of the object, you store the current date/time (note that `DateTime.Now` almost certainly has insufficient precision to be useful) and provide some means of exposing that information publicly.

Comment: _note that `DateTime.Now` almost certainly has insufficient precision to be useful_ Well, if one of the objects was created yesterday, and the other one was created today, the precision might be OK, since `DateTime.Now` updates itself regularly.

Comment: I agree there's no way to absolutely check for "ctor time", but I wonder if you could get a comparative check via forking off into `ICorDebug` land, getting your FReachable path, and making some educated guesses on relative lengths/position in heap, etc...although, with compaction and whatnot, position in any heap would not help much.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Very, very few people are writing programs that are running for a day straight, or in particular have objects within that program that are alive for a day straight.  "almost certainly" might be a bit much, I suppose "quite likely" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @JerKimball And you've apparently reached the conclusion yourself as to why that won't work.  As soon as even a first level GC collection takes place you no longer can rely on the pointer position to determine age.  And even then, if one object managed to get placed in the large object heap that would affect it, and all around it's just doomed to fail since the GC can move stuff around freely.

Comment: @Servy, and there goes my (apparently not so) brilliant idea :P

Comment: Ah crap, forgot about the LOH. Hmm...**thinking hard** What about pulling out the `SyncBlock` right before the object instance - although that would only help if it were involved in any critical sections...

Comment: @JerKimball Fundamentally, even if something like that would work, it would a) almost certainly rely on implementation details not specified in the spec and potentially break in some future version b) be very confusing for anyone trying to use the code.  Just grabbing the current time in a constructor and storing it somewhere makes sense, but going much beyond that would be highly confusing to others using your code.  Don't be mean to them.

Comment: Hah - fair enough; Honestly, at this point I'm just trying to figure out if there's any convoluted way to abuse the (specifically x86/4.0 runtime) compiler/jitter...Ooh! Ooh! What about the Interface/IVMap in the ObjInstance block? Those get added on first occurrence, so if you had *two* different types, you might be able to suss out some sort of ordering there...(edit - although now that I think about it, it'd only tell you what type loaded first)

Answer (score 0):

Short of `storing` it - you can also `log` the timestamp somewhere.
(Being that the most obvious purpose for this could be some form of debugging that makes sense)

Still it won't work for arbitrary objects, unless you have full control.

Most solutions derive from practical needs, this comes up rarely - if you need anything like that you can make a `custom factory` for 3rd party objects, or your own implementation for ones you own.